# ANSI Russian docx to unicode

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, unicode, documents, ansi

I've a big ms-word doc file which contains ANSI encoded russian texts and some fomula's with special formatting.

I would like to know is there any tool using which I convert the "ANSI" encoded doc file into "unicode" encoded one keeping all the formatting and formulas ?

I need to convert the only the text encoding (ANSI > UTF_8), **and need to keep the original doc formatting and formulas**

Comment: This seems to be question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719039/convert-massive-ascii-doc-to-unicode-doc reborn. Apparently “ANSI” stands for windows-1251. The .doc format does not have a settable character encoding; Word plays with encodings only when reading or writing other data formats, like plain text. Explaining *why* you think you need to do the conversion might help to see what the real problem is.